# Send an email between two blackberry simulators

Tags: blackberry, outlook, blackberry-simulator

I am testing a BlackBerry application using the email server simulator. I have tried to send an email from Microsoft Outlook Express to the BlackBerry device simulator using the email server simulator, and that is successful. But I am not successful sending an email from the device simulator to Outlook Express. From the simulator, it appears the email is sent successfully, but it is not received by Microsoft Outlook Express.

The above one is sending the mail between two blackberry simulator in stand alone mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer by myself.the resolution to the question follows.

go to microsoft outlook express .then click the send/receive menu in the menu bar.
pop-up menu appears , in which click the account you have in the  outlook express.

Comment: i was found it by myself. without referring any sites